# How to upload an image as an input field in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

There are multiple input fields as text/integer/date... and **image** 
everything works just fine, selecting a file is smooth and slick but uploading it into the database gives me an error that goes:

```
 TypeError: _this.state.selectedFile is null


// ************Pets
>
onSubmit = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const {
      name ``
      `
```

**Here is the code (the error most probably is from the *state*):**

```
const endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/upload";

class Pets extends Component {
state = {
// error_message: "",
pets_list: [],
selectedFile: null,
loaded: 0
 };

//For image upload with Loading bar

 handleSelectedFile = event => {
 this.setState({
  selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
  loaded: 0
   });
  };
  handleUpload = () => {
   const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", this.state.selectedFile,       
   this.state.selectedFile.name);
   axios
  .post(endpoint, data, {
    onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
      this.setState({
        loaded: (ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total) * 100
      });
    }
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.statusText);
  });
 };
   ...
```

**Then later in the input we have:**

```
   <div>
          <input
            style={{ margin: "10px" }}
            type="file"
            name=""
            id=""
            onChange={this.handleSelectedFiles}
          />
          <button onClick={this.handleUpload}>Upload</button>
          <div>{Math.round(this.state.loaded, 2)} %</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**The error points here**

```
onSubmit = evt => {
evt.preventDefault();
const {
  name,
  image,
  gender,
  date_of_birth,
  species,
  info,
  availabilty
} = this.state;
```

**Let me know if further code is needed.**

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney TypeError: _this.state.selectedFile is null

Comment: You have `onChange={this.handleSelectedFiles}` but the method is called `handleSelectedFile`